# How charge can make potential energy?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, potential-energy

so currently im learning about electricity and while im learning, i have some difficulties. i'm got really confused to understand the difference between electric potential with electric potential energy. but instead of asking the difference which have already stated in a lot of articles.

if object was pull by gravity so it can get a gravitional potential energy, what make charges (q) move? is it need charges to move? (because based on electric potential energy, the formula have 2 charges).

P.S. feel free if you want to add some refrences of book that you feel can help a senior high school student to learn about electricity. Thanks you

Answer (score -3):

[image]Charge cannot make potential energy.I will explain it in layman terms.Imagine there are two charge +q and +q in a isolated environment.I am assuming that you know Coulombs law.Both the particles repel each other.Now imagine you take one of those charges and bring them close to the second one.You will have to do work in order to do so,you do it slowly so that the kinetic energy does not change.The work that you have just done is the difference in Potential Energy between the two particles.I will attach its maths down below. We usually compare the difference in potential from Infinity and consider that Potential energy of two particles are 0 at that point.Now that we have talked about potential energy I will explain Electric Potential,Imagine the same two charges, I am again assuming that you know that concept of electric fields,Now the position of one of the charges as fixed and move the other charge.Potential is defined as work done by the charge to move to a point divided by the magnitude of charge,its known as a test charge.The electric potential is given by integral of E.dr where r varies from the charge,this is also compared from infinity and electric potential of a point is compared from infinity where it is zero.All the math is attached.Also there is also a gravitational potential and potential energy.Both of these topics are very similar [image]enter image description here
Good learning

Comment: Please do not include quasi-illegible images in your answer. Also, punctuation improves readability.

Comment: If you want to have mathematical derivations/proofs, you should type them using MathJax, not a picture from a textbook.

Comment: Im sorry Im quite new here,can you teach me how to use mathjax?